# What will be the current of a 24 V ATX power supply?

Tags: power-supply, atx

I have an ATX power supply with a +12 V 8 A line and a -12 V 0.8 A line. I assume if I used the -12 V as ground to provide 24 V, then the maximum current provided by the 24 V line would be 0.8 A?

Comment: Correct. ______

Comment: @TomCarpenter 6 underscores.... is the blank "Friend"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your assumption is correct. \$\$